# recyclerview, on click Highlight and make others not highlighted

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a recyclerview of credit cards, if you click on one I want it to change the background resource of that one and make all the other ones back to default, for some reason I have been fighting this for about 5 hours and cant get it right.

Here is the failing class

```
    public class CheckOutCardRecycler extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CheckOutCardRecycler.CardViewHolder>{

    private List<Card> checkOutCard;
    private int screenWidth;
    private int selected;






    public CheckOutCardRecycler(Activity activity, List<Card> checkOutCard){


        Display display = activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        Point size = new Point();
        display.getSize(size);
        this.screenWidth = size.x;
        this.checkOutCard = checkOutCard;
        selected=-1;


    }



    public static class CardViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
         CardView card;
         LinearLayout row;
        static TextView etCardNumber;
        static TextView etName;
        static TextView etDate;
        static LinearLayout creditCard;



        CardViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            card = (CardView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_view);
            etCardNumber = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.etCardNumber);
            etName = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.etName);
            etDate = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.etDate);
            creditCard = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.creditCard);

        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return checkOutCard.size();
    }

    public int getSelected() {
        return selected;
    }

    public int getPaymentMethod(int i) {
        return Integer.parseInt(checkOutCard.get(i).getId());
    }


    @Override
    public CardViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_checkout_cards, viewGroup, false);
        CardViewHolder pvh = new CardViewHolder(v);

        return pvh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final CardViewHolder cardViewHolder, final int i) {
        CardViewHolder.etCardNumber.setText("**** **** **** " + checkOutCard.get(i).getLast_four_digits());
        CardViewHolder.etName.setText(checkOutCard.get(i).getName());
        CardViewHolder.etDate.setText(checkOutCard.get(i).getExpiry_month() +"/"+checkOutCard.get(i).getExpiry_year().substring(2,4));
        if (selected<0)
            if (checkOutCard.get(i).getDefaultcard()==1){
                selected=i;
            }

        CardViewHolder.creditCard.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {

                if (i!=selected) {

                    checkOutCard.get(selected).setDefaultcard(0);
                    checkOutCard.get(i).setDefaultcard(1);
                    selected=-1;

                    notifyDataSetChanged();




                }
            }
        });


        if (selected==i){
            if (checkOutCard.get(i).getBrand().toLowerCase().equals("visa"))
                CardViewHolder.creditCard.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.paymentscreenvisaselected);
            else if (checkOutCard.get(i).getBrand().toLowerCase().equals("mastercard"))
                CardViewHolder.creditCard.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.paymentscreenmastercardselected);
            else
                CardViewHolder.creditCard.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.paymentscreenselected);
        }
        else {

            if (checkOutCard.get(i).getBrand().toLowerCase().equals("visa"))
                CardViewHolder.creditCard.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.paymentscreenvisa);
            else if (checkOutCard.get(i).getBrand().toLowerCase().equals("mastercard"))
                CardViewHolder.creditCard.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.paymentscreenmastercard);
            else
                CardViewHolder.creditCard.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.paymentscreen);

        }


    }

    @Override
    public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);

    }




}
```

Comment: can you highlight more than one at a time ?

Comment: No just one.  It is essentially the selected card

Comment: Try not to attach clicklisteners in onBindViewHolder when you can do the same in the ViewHolder's constructor. This way you won't need to keep attaching a listener as the user scrolls. I have added a working solution in the answer. Hope you find it useful.

Comment: It is difficult to offer solutions when the problem
statement is simply, "it doesn't work".  Please [edit] your
question to give a more complete description of what you
expected to happen and how that differs from the actual
results.  See [ask] for hints on what makes a good
explanation.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks everyone for your answers, finally after days of trying all of your solutions and none of them working and not working out why I finally figured it out, I had a stupid syntax problem that was causing me headaches.

All I had to do was inside onBindViewHolder I had to change all of the CardViewHolder to cardViewHolder.  I guess that makes this question pretty pointless for other people so my apolgies and thanks again for all the effort the other people who made lengthly answers put in

Answer (score 1):

ruffly your adapter should look something like this:

```
public class CardAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CardAdapter.CardViewHolder> {
    private Context context;
    private List<Card> checkOutCard;
    private int screenWidth; // I really think you shouldn't calculate your width in the adapter but before your create it.
    private Card selected;

    public CardAdapter(Context context, List<Card> checkOutCard, int screenWidth) {
        this.context = context;
        this.screenWidth = screenWidth;
        this.checkOutCard = checkOutCard;
    }

    protected Context getContext() {
        return context;
    }

    protected Card getItem(int position){

    }

    public Card getSelected() {
        return selected;
    }

    public void setSelected(Card selected) {
        this.selected = selected;
    }

    @Override
    public CardViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return new CardViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_checkout_cards, parent, false));
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(CardViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Card currentCard = getItem(position);
        holder.bind(currentCard, currentCard == selected);

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return 0;
    }

    public static class CardViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        CardView card;
        LinearLayout row;
        static TextView etCardNumber;
        static TextView etName;
        static TextView etDate;
        static LinearLayout creditCard;

        CardViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            card = (CardView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_view);
            etCardNumber = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.etCardNumber);
            etName = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.etName);
            etDate = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.etDate);
            creditCard = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.creditCard);

        }

        public void bind(Card card, boolean isSelected){
            etCardNumber.setText("**** **** **** " + card.getLast_four_digits());
            etName.setText(card.getName());
            etDate.setText(card.getExpiry_month() +"/"+card.getExpiry_year().substring(2,4));
            if (isSelected)
                if (card.getDefaultcard()==1){
                    selected=i;
                }

            creditCard.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v)
                {

                    if (i!=selected) {

                        checkOutCard.get(selected).setDefaultcard(0);
                        card.setDefaultcard(1);
                        selected=-1;

                        notifyDataSetChanged();




                    }
                }
            });


            if (selected==i){
                if (card.getBrand().toLowerCase().equals("visa"))
                    creditCard.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.paymentscreenvisaselected);
                else if (card.getBrand().toLowerCase().equals("mastercard"))
                    creditCard.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.paymentscreenmastercardselected);
                else
                    creditCard.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.paymentscreenselected);
            }
            else {

                if (card.getBrand().toLowerCase().equals("visa"))
                    creditCard.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.paymentscreenvisa);
                else if (card.getBrand().toLowerCase().equals("mastercard"))
                    creditCard.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.paymentscreenmastercard);
                else
                    creditCard.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.paymentscreen);

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working example:

The adapter:

```
public class TestAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<TestAdapter.TestViewHolder> {


    private List<String> mData;
    Context mContext;
    RecyclerView mRecyclerView;


    public class TestViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        LinearLayout mListItemLayout;
        TextView mTextView;
        int mPosition;

        public TestViewHolder(final View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mListItemLayout = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_item);
            mTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_text);
            mListItemLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                    grayBackgroundOfOtherItems();
                }
            });

        }

        public void setPosition(int position){
            mPosition = position;
        }

        private void grayBackgroundOfOtherItems(){

            int size = mData.size();
            for(int i=0; i<size; i++){
                if(i != mPosition){
                    TestViewHolder viewHolder = (TestViewHolder) mRecyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(i);
                    ((TestViewHolder) mRecyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(i)).
                                           mListItemLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);
                }
            }
        }

    }

    public TestAdapter(Context context, RecyclerView recyclerView){

        this.mContext = context;
        this.mRecyclerView = recyclerView;
        initData();
    }

    private void initData(){

        mData = new ArrayList<String>();
        mData.add("Africa");
        mData.add("Antartica");
        mData.add("Asia");
        mData.add("Australia");
        mData.add("Europe");
        mData.add("North America");
        mData.add("South America");
    }

    @Override
    public TestViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recycler_item, parent, false);
        TestViewHolder viewHolder = new TestViewHolder(view);
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(TestViewHolder holder, int position) {

        holder.mTextView.setText(mData.get(position));
        holder.setPosition(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mData.size();
    }
}
```

The Activity:

```
public class CardViewActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

    RecyclerView mRecyclerView;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_card_view);

        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(new TestAdapter(this,mRecyclerView));
    }
}
```

The Activity's layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".stack_overflow_cardview.CardViewActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And each list item's layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id = "@+id/list_item"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

    <TextView
        android:id = "@+id/list_item_text"
        android:layout_width = "wrap_content"
        android:layout_height = "wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And a screenshot:

[image]

Hope this was useful.

Edit: If you are not happy coupling your RecyclerView by bringing a reference of it inside your Adapter, you could use an interface that your Activity / Fragment must implement and pass the position to the interface method.